# How to find distinct records using aggregate query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Need an help with group by query in mongo db. I need to find the distinct account numbers from a collection where it matches the ID : ABC_00000000003.

I have written below query but for some reason its not pulling all distinct records. Please correct me if anything wrong in this query.

Appreciate your help.

```
db.controlDocument.aggregate([{$match:{"ID": "ABC_00000000003"}}, {$group:{"_id": "$AccountNumber"}}])
```

Before using this query i used below query but it failing when the collection contains more than 1 million records.

```
db.controlDocument.distinct("AccountNumber", {"ID" : "ABC_00000000003"})
```

Below is the exception i'm getting when i'm trying above distinct query in Robo mongo. And even in my java program i'm facing similary issue. In my QA DB, the collection i'm trying to query against contains 280k records and my production collection contains nearly 1 million records. Need a better query which could give the results in few secs. So i tried to written a aggregate query to get same distinct records but i'm seeing difference in the count between these 2 queries if i write query to pull some smaller result set.

```
Error: distinct failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "distinct too big, 16mb cap", "code" : 17217 } :
DBCollection.prototype.distinct@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1650:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Can you give me a sample of your data?

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me here. I'm editing my post so there will be better readability.

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that the result set contains a lot of documents (more than 16MB worth of data). How many distinct values are you expecting to get within one result set? Your aggregation query looks ok, so if you get a different count between the aggregation and the `distinct` query, there may be something else going on. Please provide sample documents, and how much the count differs.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the response. 
When i used distinct query in my java program i got the result set count as 135 for a different account number which has less documents in the collection. But for same account number i got result set count as 105 when i used the aggregate query. And i'm confused now, where its going wrong. When i validate the records from distinct query its looks correct to me. At this point i'm not sure how many distinct records i will be getting out of collection as i'm getting different count with both queries. Can you also advise how to resolve this exception?